# Lavarel query with condition

Tags: laravel, conditional-statements, relationship

I have a `User` table/model with an `approved` column, that is a boolean.

I have a `Post` table/model, with an `user_id` foreign key.

Relationship within the `Post` model:

```
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(
    User::class,
    'user_id'
  )->first();
}
```

How can I list all of the `Post`s that come from `User`s with approved = true?

Comment: Do you have a `user()` relationship set up in your `Post` model? If so, please may you add the code for it to your question.

Comment: use laravel's relationships for achieve the goal. You ca see the documenataion https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: @Rwd I have added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First fix your relationship in the `Post` model, change it to the following:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

You can read more about the inverse of the one-to-many relationship [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse).

Then you can use something like this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use App\Post;

$posts = Post::whereHas('user', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('approved', 1);
})->get();
```

This will get all posts that have a user where the approved column is set to `true`.

You can read more about `whereHas` [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in 2 ways:

```
$users=User::where('approved', true)->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $posts=Post::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
}
```

or, you can use join()

```
$users=Users::where('approved', true)->join('posts', 'posts.user_id', '=', 
   'users.id')->get();

$posts=Post::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 
   'posts.user_id')->where('users.approved', true)->get();
```

Comment: I prefer the second way, however, isn't there a way that will give me instances of ```Post``` instead of ```User```?

Comment: @user3421985 I add another join query that can be usefull

Comment: @Hossein The `$posts` variable in your first solution is overwritten in each loop, how would this work? And these are very simple relations, I don't know why you would use joins if it is supported by eloquent out of the box.

Comment: @Remul true. you can append $posts to a helper array each time.

Comment: @Remul @Hossein Thank you both, I have chosen Remul's solution because it returns the needed instances of the ```Post``` model in a cleaner way, without all of the user info in each instance.

Comment: @user3421985 you can also use select() in your query to filter output attributes.like ->select(posts.*)